# Drupal7 Forms API: Ajax button not firing callback

Tags: ajax, forms, drupal, drupal-7, ajaxform

I'm really stumped here. I've an ajax form with a button - actually, the one below has both a button and a select object, both calling the same callback function.

What I want: the button to call the callback, but not submit the form.

What I have: the select calls the callback just fine, but the submit button doesn't do *anything.*

Thoughts?

```
function my_module_pane_checkout_form($form, $form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {
  $pane_form = array(); 

  $pane_form['codes'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="codes-fieldset-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  $pane_form['codes']['add_code_0'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#options' => array(1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'my_module_pane_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'codes-fieldset-wrapper',
    ),
    '#default_value' => 1,
  );

  $pane_form['codes']['add_code'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Add Code',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'my_module_pane_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'codes-fieldset-wrapper',
    ),
  );

  return $pane_form;
}

function my_module_pane_callback($form, $form_state) {
  watchdog('php', 'inside callback');
  return $form['my_module'];
}
```

Comment: To be noted: this form is sitting on a commerce checkout pane (ah, the joy).

Answer (score 3):

I added `'#limit_validation_errors' => array()` and changed the `submit` to a `button` and got it working, but not after a tremendous headache (and a full day's work lost).

This form is sitting on a commerce checkout pane. With a submit button, the form is *always* coming up submitted (in the ajax_form_callback function the $form_state object always had submitted=1), whether I had set 'prevent' => 'click' in the #ajax array (since Drupal ajax fires on mousedown) or had set '#executes_submit_handler' => FALSE. As such, the form was always validating, and since not everything was filled in, it wasn't passing.

With the button the form was still running validation (and failing) but the form was not marked as submitted.

Therefore the JSON payload was empty of any commands for the button because it failed validation. Since the select (or any other object) wasn't submitting the form or checking validation, that element's ajax call was working.

Since we need to pass both checks in order to build the form and the ajax commands array, we need the element type to be a button, and we need to set the limit validation errors to an empty array - Drupal will then only run checks on the elements passed in the array - and for this we want nothing.

Once again: change `'#type' => 'submit'` to `'#type' => 'button'` and add `'#limit_validation_errors' => array()`.

```
function my_module_pane_checkout_form($form, $form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {
  $pane_form = array(); 

  $pane_form['codes'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="codes-fieldset-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  $pane_form['codes']['add_code_0'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#options' => array(1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'my_module_pane_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'codes-fieldset-wrapper',
    ),
    '#default_value' => 1,
  );

  $pane_form['codes']['add_code'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => 'Add Code',
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'my_module_pane_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'codes-fieldset-wrapper',
    ),
  );

  return $pane_form;
}

function my_module_pane_callback($form, $form_state) {
  watchdog('php', 'inside callback');
  return $form['my_module'];
}
```